# Pandas dataframe: Listing amount of people per gender in each major

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry about the vague title, but I didn't know how to word it.

So I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns and any amount of rows. The first column is a person's name, the second column is their major (six possible majors, always written the same), and the third column is their gender (always 'Male' or 'Female').

I was told to print out the number of people in each major, which I was able to accomplish by saying table.Qmajor.value_counts() (table being my dataframe variable name). Now I am being asked to print the amount of males and females in each major, and I have no idea where to start. Any help is appreciated.

The column names are Qnames, Qmajor, and Qgender.

Comment: df.groupby('Qgender')['Qmajor'].count()

Comment: When I entered that, it just output the total amount of males and the total amount of females in the dataframe.

Comment: @user3204121 can you have a .head() of your dataframe so that we could understand better?

Comment: @VaishaliGarg Actually, `df.groupby(['Qgender','Qmajor']).count() `.

Comment: @DYZ, yeah right, that was an oversight. Thank you!

Comment: @user3204121 Sir, you should accept the answer given, if it solves your problem, that's the common practice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

altering @VaishaliGarg's answer a little, 
you can use

`df.groupby(['Qgender','Qmajor']).count()`

Also if needed a dataframe out of it, we need to add .reset_index()
since it would be a groupbyObject.

`df.groupby(['Qgender','Qmajor']).count().reset_index()`

Comment: count() doesn't take an argument like count('gender')

Comment: @VaishaliGarg yeah right, that was an oversight :p THANKS